# php variable does not increment inside of mysqli_stmt_fetch() while loop

Tags: php, ajax, while-loop

I am building a chat application which updates via Server-Sent Events. I have a problem with my code which seeks to increment the value for searching for new messages:

```
include("../services/db_connect.php");
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
$messages = array();
$lastMessageID=0;
$stmt="SELECT messageID FROM chat_messages ORDER BY messageID DESC LIMIT 1";
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $stmt)){
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $lastMessageID);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

while(true){
    $stmt2 = "SELECT chat_messages.messageID, chat_messages.userID, chat_messages.messageTime, chat_messages.messageText, chat_user.username FROM chat_messages, chat_user WHERE chat_messages.userID = chat_user.userID AND chat_messages.messageID > ? ORDER BY chat_messages.messageID ASC";
    $rows =0;
    if($stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($db, $stmt2)){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, "i", $lastMessageID);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt2, $messageID, $userID, $messageTime, $messageText, $username);

        while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt2)){
            array_push($messages, array(
                "mID" => $messageID,
                "userID" => $userID,
                "messageTime" =>$messageTime,
                "messageText" =>$messageText,
                "username" =>$username
            ));
            $lastMessageID++;
        }
    }
    echo("data:".json_encode($messages)."\n\n");
    @ob_flush(); @flush();
    sleep(4);
}
```

Without entering any messages, the script outputs data:[] as it should but when enter a couple of messages it would keep looping with the json string of only the two new variables which means that the $lastMessageID variable does not update. Can anyone explain what is wrong with the script?

Comment: Please break out while loop when done

Comment: Why would I need to break out of the while loop? Isn't the use of the while loop the reason for the persistent updates to the chat? If I broke out of the while loop, it would only return one json string of data and no more.

Comment: Break only if data found

Comment: I see. Thats another way of doing it I guess. But I have the Javascript checking for an empty array so I just needed to find a way to increment the $lastMessageID variable in order to filter the new mysql searches

Comment: If you don't break while loop, your script will not terminate.

Comment: I don't want my script to terminate. I check on the client side with JavaScript to determine if there is new data to display

Comment: Is it possible the client is breaking the connection, and then re-invoking your script?  Also, make sure that automatic gzip compression is not turned on in PHP or on the server.  Also, try a simple loop that doesn't use a database and simply sends out a dummy message every 4 seconds and see if the client is receiving them.

Answer (score 0):

The $messages array should be initialized inside of the while loop instead. This is so that the array being sent to the client only has the new mysql resultset and not the previous stored rows as well. Simple programming principles were ignored on my part.